# Program only writing to file if I manually close it?

Tags: java, io

**KnockKnockServer File**

This starts the server

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Create new Server object
         * Call run() on new Server object
         */
        KnockKnockServer kks = new KnockKnockServer();
        kks.run();

    }
```

This starts new threads and opens up the log file.

```
 private void run(){
        try {
            File logfile = new File("prog1b.log");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(logfile);
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(fos, true);
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5520);
            while(true){
                try {
                    Socket serverClient = serverSocket.accept();
                    KnockKnockServerThread kkst = new KnockKnockServerThread(serverClient, out);
                    kkst.start();
                } catch (IOException evt) {
                    System.out.println("Error");
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException evt) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }
```

**KnockKnockThread file**

```
public KnockKnockServerThread(Socket clientSocket, PrintWriter logfile) {
            serverClient = clientSocket;
            lOut = logfile;
        }
```

This does the writing to the file and replies to the client.

```
public void run() {
            try {
                sOut = new PrintWriter(serverClient.getOutputStream(), true);
                lOut.write(formatter.format(date) + ": Client connected from " + serverClient.getRemoteSocketAddress() + " on port # " + serverClient.getPort() + ".\n");
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serverClient.getInputStream()));

                String clientMessage = "", serverMessage = "";

                while (!clientMessage.equals("quit")) {
                    clientMessage = in.readLine();
                    if(!clientMessage.equals("quit")) {
                        serverMessage = encrypt(clientMessage);
                        sOut.println(serverMessage);
                        lOut.write(formatter.format(date) + " Client " + serverClient.getPort() + ": " + clientMessage + "\n");
                        lOut.write(formatter.format(date) + " Server: " + serverMessage + "\n");
                    }
                    else if(clientMessage.equals("quit")){
                        sOut.println("Good Bye!\n");
                        lOut.write(formatter.format(date) + ": Connection closed on port " + serverClient.getPort() + ".\n");
                    }
                }
                sOut.close();
                in.close();
                serverClient.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Error");

            }
        }
```

The general gist of the program

For whatever reason, I can only see text in the log file when I manually close the file. Otherwise it is entirely blank. I can't find anything online to help. I thought maybe it was going back to the first run() and making a new file which would clear the text but I put print statements everywhere and that was not the case. I am thoroughly confused. I can't close the file as the server needs to be ready to write to the log file from other threads.

Comment: With the quantity of text you're writing, it's almost certainly not flushing to the file until you close it.

Comment: @MichaelBerry Apologies, I'm a noob at this and I don't really understand how flush() works. I thought that since autoflush was on I wouldn't have to worry about it. Evidently not. But at what points do I need to flush, and why?

Comment: Actually i think i get it. Say the toilet bowl is the buffer, the pipe is the process, and the outlet is the file. When im performing IO operations on the file they stay in the bowl until i flush the toilet from which the pipes carry them to the outlet (which would be my file). Am i understanding that correctly?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to write the data to the file sooner, you need to call **flush()** on the stream. This is because the data is usually buffered for I/O performance. From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush) of the `flush` method:

> Flushes the output stream and forces any buffered output bytes to be written out. The general contract of flush is that calling it is an indication that, if any bytes previously written have been buffered by the implementation of the output stream, such bytes should immediately be written to their intended destination.

Answer (score 2):

Typically file I/O is buffered.  What you'll need to do is flush the file (which happens automatically when you close the file, but can also be done on its own by calling the relevant method).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the try with resources and see if this solves your problem:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-try-with-resources

Answer (score 0):

If you delve into `Unix` a bit, file I/O is buffered. When you for example, write to a file, you'll use the system call:

`write(file_descriptor,user_space_buffer,count)`.

You write from the buffer into the file (that resides on the disk). What `write(...)` does is that it copies the data from the buffer in the user-space to the kernel buffer and return immediately. This is done so that the call does not take a lot of time (as disk I/O is expensive).

Closing a file will release the file descriptor and flush the buffer.

Note: You can also do direct I/O bypassing the kernel level buffer.